# swagger oauth security definition

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, swagger

On my current webapi project I have set a swagger oauth security definition with implicit flow and authorize url https://login.microsoftonline.com/ + tenant Id. The scopes are the same as in the github exapmle for the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore nuget , this is the link https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. But when i try to authenticate on swagger online editor, this one https://editor.swagger.io/, I can't get the token back and get a 404 exception. What do I need to set in my azure portal registered app to return a token back to the online swagger editor ?

Comment: Please have a look at the redirect_uri being passed in the request and the ones registered for the app.

Comment: I added this url http://localhost:3200/oauth2-redirect.html to my redirect url but it still returns AADSTS50001. After that I changed my authorize url to  https://login.microsoftonline.com/ + tenant name + /oauth/authorize but it still returns AADSTS50001 Resource identifier is not provided

Comment: Check https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

See if this documentation helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit

Also if your client is the swagger editor then localhost:3200 url may not be applicable when the request is made from swagger editor.

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I created my .Net Core 2.0 Web API application and created the AAD app on Azure Portal. The configuration under **ConfigureServices** would look like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
// Configure the app to use Jwt Bearer Authentication
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
    jwtOptions.Authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://sts.windows.net/{0}/", Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]);
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:WebApiApp:ClientId"];
});
```

For Swagger UI, I also created a new AAD app on Azure Portal and add permissions to access the Web API app as follows:

[image]

Then, I added the following code snippet for defining the OAuth2.0 scheme as follows:

```
// Define the OAuth2.0 scheme that's in use (i.e. Implicit Flow)
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
{
    Type = "oauth2",
    Flow = "implicit",
    AuthorizationUrl = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/authorize", Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]),
    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "user_impersonation", "Access Bruce-WebAPI-NetCore" }
    }
});
// Enable operation filter based on AuthorizeAttribute
c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
```

And use the following code for initializing the middleware to serve swagger-ui.

```
// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.ConfigureOAuth2(
        Configuration["AzureAd:SwaggerApp:ClientId"],
        Configuration["AzureAd:SwaggerApp:ClientSecret"],
        Configuration["AzureAd:SwaggerApp:RedirectUri"], //http://localhost:30504/swagger/o2c.html
        "Bruce-WebAPI-NetCore-Swagger",
        additionalQueryStringParameters: new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            { "resource",Configuration["AzureAd:WebApiApp:ClientId"]}
    });
});
```

**Test:**

[image]

[image]

> > but it still returns AADSTS50001 Resource identifier is not provided

During my processing, I encountered the similar issue. At last, I found that the `resource` parameter is not specified. Then, I set the `additionalQueryStringParameters` parameter for `ConfigureOAuth2`. Here is my code sample [WebAPI-Swagger-NetCore](https://github.com/brucechen1019/WebAPI-Swagger-NetCore), you could refer to it.

Moreover, for adding access scopes to your resource application (Web API), you could follow the **Adding access scopes to your resource application** section under [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications#adding-an-application). Also, my `SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter` did not assign the scope requirements to operations based on `AuthorizeAttribute` provided [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/test/WebSites/OAuth2Integration/ResourceServer/Swagger/SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter.cs). You could specific the supported scopes under `AddSecurityDefinition`, then for your controller or action you could mark it as `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer", Policy = "{scope}")]`. Details, you could follow this [sample](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/master/test/WebSites/OAuth2Integration).