# How to configure swagger with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt, swagger, azure-active-directory

I'm currently developing an app in asp.net core 2.  However, i'm having issue configuring swagger properly and the authentication layer for the webapi.

In my instance, I have a web api that is configured with jwt.  It uses the app id url as the jwt audience.  Swagger is configured to run on top of this service and AAD is set up.  However, because it's logging in to itself it has the resource configured as the web api client ID.  Login successfully works, but the token does not work  with the api calls.  The main reason is that there is difference in resource/audience.  The token is configured with an audience of the client ID and the webapi is conifgured with a jwtaudience of the app ID URL.

It only works if i configure the jwtAudience to the clientID.  I doesn't work if i try to update the swagger resource as the app ID URL.

I need the jwtAudience to be configured to the APP ID URL.  I can't figure how to do this thou.

Do i need to modify the AAD manifest to give permission to itself?

Any advice appreciated?
Thanks,
Derek

Comment: You could follow this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057672/swagger-oauth-security-definition/48073209#48073209

Comment: @BruceChen this is not the same.  I want the jwtAudience to be the app id url.  In that example, it uses the clientId and that is why it works.